# Databinding a ListBox with SelectionMode = Multiple

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a WPF `ListBox` that I would like to

- Enable multiple selection in the `ListBox`, and
- Databind the ListBox to my view model.

These two requirements appear to be incompatible. My view model has an `ObservableCollection<T>` property to bind to this ListBox; I set up a binding in XAML from the property to the `ListBox.SelectedItems` property. When I compiled, I got an error saying that the `SelectedItems` property was read only and could not be set from XAML.

Am I binding to the wrong control property? Is there a way to bind a multiple-selection ListBox in XAML to a view model collection property? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using a bit of code-behind in a SelectionChanged event handler to set the view model property. Simpler than creating object wrappers.

Answer (score 23):

What you can do to get around this:

Create an IsSelected property on the items you are displaying in the list. Im assuming these are represented by a view model as well. So it shouldn't be a drama to add an extra property. If they are just business objects consider using a wrapper class to painlessly wrap them in view model items (shameless plug - [here](http://mvvmwrapper.codeplex.com/) is one such system. I use it daily to wrap my business objects)

Use an items container style to bind the IsSelected property of the list box item to the IsSelected property of the items you are displaying, like so

```
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <!-- This Style binds a ListBoxItem to a the ViewModelItem. -->
       <Style
          TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
          <Setter
             Property="IsSelected"
             Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
       </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(might need a based on attribute on the style, not sure)

Now whenever a list box item gets selected your view model will know about it and can update its internal collection as required.

Comment: I wish you included the viewmodel code... Not sure what datatypes should be used on the property.

Comment: The IsSelected property is a Boolean.

Comment: It's a very nice solution. Just in case, for a DataGrid, the  Xaml is :
   
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
                      ...
                    </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a technique for allowing a read-only binding to the `SelectedItems` property of a WPF DataGrid just by extending the DataGrid that I believe could easily be co-opted for a ListBox. You can see my post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16953833/62278