# UWP listview binding

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

what is the easiest way to bind selected state of listview's item to model's boolean property?

I have model:

```
class Model {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

And listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I bind items to the listview:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = // list of Model instances
```

I want the Selected property of Model to always reflect whether it is selected or not in myListView. So - by selecting/deselecting the item in myListView, it will hold the apropriate bool value or by setting Selected property myListView will select/deselect appropriate item.

Comment: I think you should be able to use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2511836/60761). Post back to let us know if/how that works for UWP.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not sure where exactly to paste code from that answer. I pasted it between ListView tags. Then I get error: Type is not supported in a Windows Universal project and The member IsSelected is not recongnized or is not accessible.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the easiest way to bind selected state of listview's item to model's boolean property?

I'm not sure if this is the most easiest way, but for me I think it is the easiest way to bind [SelectorItem.IsSelected property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selectoritem.isselected.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of `ListViewItem` to your `Selected` property in model. Only the problem is, we all know each item of `ListView` is an instance of `ListViewItem`, but when we use `DataTemplate` to build the item structure for `ListViewItem`, `ListViewItem`s are not available in design-time. So my idea is to bind this property in code behind, just for example here:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" SelectionMode="Multiple" Loaded="myListView_Loaded" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Collection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

code behind:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Model> Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Collection.Add(new Model { Name = "Name " + i });
    }
}

private void myListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<ListViewItem> lvItems = FindVisualChildren<ListViewItem>(myListView);
    if (lvItems != null)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvitem in lvItems)
        {
            Model model = lvitem.Content as Model;
            Binding b = new Binding
            {
                Source = model,
                Path = new PropertyPath("Selected"),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(lvitem, ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, b);
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _Selected;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Selected)
            {
                _Selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well, thank you! However, is there a way to transform the C# code that performs binding of Selected property to IsSelectedProperty directly into XAML - it would be more readable.

Comment: There is a problem with the code - myListView has visibility==collapsed when seriesListView_Loaded is called (I display myListView later) which causes the binding not to be set.

Comment: @MartinDusek, as I said in my answer, ListViewItem in this scenario is not available in xaml. so I can't bind it in xaml code. You can put this method in other [events of ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#events), but I think it's better to excute this code when you want make it visible. I think it's not a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the perfect way would be to implement the [ListView.ItemSelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, and iterate through each item in the list view model to set it to true for the item which is selected, false for the rest items.

However, You may want to try something like this, although honestly I'm not sure if this is the correct way:

```
class Model {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected 
    {
        get
        {
            return MyListView.SelectedItems.Count(x => x.Name == Name) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you find `MyListView` in your data model?